# Removing Malwares from client system

Tags: malware

I am stuck with one issue here. There are some adshowing malwares which are loading on top of my website at the client's system. These are ajax calls happening in between my requests.

I suspect these malwares are resulting in increased page load time for my site.

[image: Check out this image]

Comment: Is the problem specific for one of your clients or it happens always on every machine?

Comment: Hi andrew ... its not specific to a single client infact its happening on many machines..
Also this is the most time consuming ajax call happening

Comment: So it seem to be server-side problem. What is you backend exactly? Apache/PHP or something else?

Comment: Yeah .. thats what I suspected . Django it is ...the backend !

Comment: There might be some javascript stored on the server but being executed on the client which downloads that waste. So you could search in js files.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a browser related one, best is to try use AdwCleaner.

When I had some "weird" issues with the browser this one solved the issue.

If you haven't already, give it a try!

Comment: I am monitoring the website and I am not the user . So, If I dont ask the user to use adwcleaner , is there any other way I can block these requests at my end only.